# How do I get promise's finally() to work in Edge?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

Basically, I have a function that returns a promise and calling `finally()` doesn't appear to be working on Edge. It is fine in **IE11** (weird huh?) The rest of the Promise API works great. I read this could be a bug with either Edge or the Babel **Polyfill** and a workaround is to wrap it somehow, but I have not seen a code example.

**API**

I have an API that returns a promise

```
/**
 * Return a promise containing a single employee.
 *
 * @param {string} [employeeID] The employeeID.
 *
 * @return {promise} The promise. 
 */
export function getEmployee(employeeID) {
    return fetch(api + "?employeeID=" + employeeID)
        .then((resp) => {
            return resp.json();
        });
}
```

**Calling Code**

```
    getEmployee(this.props.id)
        .then((json) => {
            this.setState({
               // do some stuff
            });
        })
        .finally(() => { });
```

**Notes**

- Using Babel Polyfill
- Using WhatWG Fetch
- Using Webpack

**Error**

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'finally'

Comment: Doing this in Edge -> `Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log("do this")).finally(() => console.log("finally"))`  Shows `do this` `finally`, Are you able to knock up a reproducible test case.

Comment: It may have to do with `fetch` not returning a *native, built-in* Promise (that would inherit from `Promise.prototype.finally`), but that it returns a polyfill version that does not have a `.finally` method (not that sure though)

Comment: While I've seen weird bugs in Edge, I am not convinced about this one yet. What do you mean by not appearing to be working? Does it throw an error? Or does it jjust hang? Lets try to replucate the problem, show us some code that you consider not working in Edge, and we can run it ourselves.

Comment: Let me add the error above.

Comment: Could it be an issue with Whatwg-fetch polyfill?

Comment: `.finally(() => { });` I dont think its valid ES6

Comment: () => {} is function shorthand and transpiled via babel. The error posted is about the method finally().

Comment: @EricHarms the reason the polyfill works in IE11 but not Edge is because the shim does not polyfill each method individually. Since IE11 has _no_ `Promise` support, the entire polyfill is dropped in, but since Edge has ES2015 `Promise` support (`.finally()` was added in ES2017, but never implemented by Edge), the shim does not properly detect that `.finally()` needs to be patched on the existing native `Promise` implementation in Edge. My answer in the duplicate provides a simple patch that falls back to a polyfill if `.finally` does not already exist.

Comment: Thanks for everything. Looking at the duplicate now. Much appreciated

Comment: I dropped the following code in before my main entry point and after the babel polyfill. No luck. Promise.prototype.finally = Promise.prototype.finally || {
   finally (fn) {
     const onFinally = cb => Promise.resolve(fn()).then(cb);
     return this.then(
       result => onFinally(() => result),
       reason => onFinally(() => Promise.reject(reason))
     );
   }
 }.finally;